# Access on premise SMB file share from Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, smb, fileshare

Following is the article about Create and manage Azure Files share with Windows virtual machines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows

What we want is we have one existing file share hosted on our own on-premise data center and we want to share it AS SMB file share with Azure virtual machine where our application is hosted. Is it possible to have such hybrid kind of solution in Azure VM?

Comment: Have you researched [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/)?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can create an Azure VPN Gateway to make your on-premise host and the Azure VM can connect via the private IP directly, then the VM can access the file share on-premise. I suggest the P2S VPN if you just have one host. You can create the Azure VPN Gateway following the steps in [Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a VNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal).